# keeping track of user input totals with array list

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

Can anyone see why don't the totals update as I'm entering the inputs?

This is a rough draft of a program that's supposed to keep prompting the user for input ('apple', 'blueberry', 'peanut' only) until the user has indicated they want to quit ('q"). I've created the ArrayLists for each input to keep track of the number of times each input was entered.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListLoop {
   public static void main(String[] args) {     
      String pie = getPie();
      int aTotal = fillApple(pie);
      int bTotal = fillBlueberry(pie);
      int pTotal = fillPeanut(pie);
      if (pie.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
         print(aTotal, bTotal, pTotal);
      }  
   }

   public static String getPie() {
      String pie;
      do {
         pie = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie");     
      } while(!pie.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));     
      return pie;
   }

   public static int fillApple(String pie) {
      int appleTotal = 0;  
      ArrayList<String> apple = new ArrayList<String>();     
      if (pie.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
         apple.add(pie);         
         appleTotal++;
      }
      return appleTotal;
   }

   public static int fillBlueberry(String pie) {
      int blueberryTotal = 0;   
      ArrayList<String> blueberry = new ArrayList<String>();           
      if   (pie.equalsIgnoreCase("blueberry")) {
         blueberry.add(pie);        
         blueberryTotal++;
      }
      return blueberryTotal;
   }

   public static int fillPeanut(String pie) {
      int peanutTotal = 0;
      ArrayList<String> peanut = new ArrayList<String>();
      if (pie.equalsIgnoreCase("peanut")) {
         peanut.add(pie);        
         peanutTotal++;
      }
      return peanutTotal;
   }

   public static void print(int appleTotal, int blueberryTotal, int peanutTotal) {     
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, appleTotal + "\n" + blueberryTotal + "\n" + peanutTotal);     
   }       
}
```

Comment: If you see your own code and try to explain that to yourself ... does it still make sense? You're ignoring every input and your lists also have no value to your program.

Answer (score 1):

your ONE call to getPie() does not return until the user enters "q"...you are forcing the poor starving customer to go away without any pie :(

Comment: This is correct. Instead of having local `ArrayList` objects in each method, either make them global or use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to keep a count.

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
  pie = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie");
} while(!pie.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
```

This is the main loop of your programm. You're querying the user until you get the string "q".

Every string that you might get before that gets thrown away.

You need to put the code to handle other strings as "q" into that loop, too:

```
int aTotal = fillApple(pie);
int bTotal = fillBlueberry(pie);
int pTotal = fillPeanut(pie);
```

Though that won't work that easily.

What you - if I understood you right - basically want is counting occurrences of certain strings. Therefore you need a counter for each string you're interested in:

```
int apples = 0;
int blueberries = 0;
int peanuts = 0;
```

Then you enter your main loop

```
do {
```

query the user for a string

```
  String pie = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Want pie! ");
```

and then check if that string matches one of the strings you're interested in

```
  if (pie.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
    apples = apples + 1;
  } else if // and so on
```

and run that until the string compares to "q":

```
} while(! pie.equalsIgnoreCase ("q"));
```

After that you can present the results as you intended to do.

No need for ArrayList here.

You can expand that e.g. if the strings you're interested in aren't fixed or known before runtime to use a map, which would the map strings to their respective counters.